# Servlet and serial port

Tags: java, servlets

We need to develop centralized device management based on java. So Could you tell me how to write servlet to read serial port from client with usb token?

Comment: A servlet speaks HTTP and runs on a server. You cannot access the client's serial ports - it would be a security nightmare. Applets and/or Java may solve your problem, if you really need to go with Java in this case.

Comment: @home, wrong, Servlet doesn't necessarily speaks HTTP. You can `HttpServlet` speaks HTTP. You can, in fact, other protocols that can be managed with a servlet, provided it's a request/response prootocol.
@anhdv, Servlet sits on server side, so if you want to read client serial port, you will have to have code that runs on client machine and communicates to servlet on server side.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I must admit I did not mention that to keep it simple as it's a fairly rare case using servlet without using HTTP - my fault.

Answer (score 3):

Not easily. In order to access resources on the client outside of the protected "sandbox" in the browser you will have to do it using a signed applet that communicates with the serial port and then back to the server (through some servlet interface like a web-service, for instance)

Alternatively, you can write a "real" client application that you would have to distribute and run on the client machine. This application would, in turn, communicate with the serial port and with the server through some communication method. This could also be a servlet-based communication like a web-service.

Point is, this has very little to do with servlets as a servlet executes on the server and has nothing to do with the client.

Comment: So could we do this with asp.net?

Comment: Do you not understand the issue? You will encounter exactly the same problem over there and in all other server side programming languages and frameworks the world is aware of. They runs in server machine, not in client machine. You need to run your code in the client side in order to get it to work. E.g. an Applet. Maybe also in Silverlight (don't pin me on it, I have never used it). They runs in webbrowser (client) side and have to a certain degree access to the client machine (only if properly signed). Finally you just embed it on your webpage.